# React-router Pass Data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, frontend, react-router-dom

I am using React for my project. I am also using react-router-dom library. However, I am confusing about passing data by react-router-dom.

Here is code for Parent Component:

```js
class Parent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            Path: {
                pathname: "/child/id/1",
                state: {
                    languageChosen: "English"
                }
            }
        };
        this.onChangeLanguage = this.onChangeLanguage.bind(this);
    }
    onChangeLanguage() {
        const { Path } = this.state
        Path.state.languageChosen = 'Spanish'
        this.setState({Path})

    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
              <NavLink to={this.state.Path}>ToChild</NavLink>
              <Route
                path={`/child/id/:id`}
                render={props => (
                  <Child {...props} onChangeLanguage={this.onChangeLanguage} />
                )}
              />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

It has a state called Path. The Parent Component pass function onChangeLanguage to its Child component.

Here is Child Component:

```js
class Child extends Component {
    onChange = () => {
        this.props.onChangeLanguage;
    };
    render() {
        const { languageChosen } = this.props.location.state;
        return (
             <div>
              {languageChosen === "English" ? "English" : "Spanish"}
              <button onClick={this.onChange}>Change Language</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

If I click the `Change Lanuguage` button in Child Component, the function was called and the state in Parent Component change. The prop `LanguageChosen` also update in Child component.

However, if I refresh the page, the prop `LanguageChosen` in Child doesn't update if I press the button. It only works If I don't refresh the page.

How should I fix that. Thanks!

Comment: I am guessing it's a problem with your Router.Are you using browserRouter.And I am not sure what's is  your purpose for refreshing the page.

Comment: @Root      Yep, I am using browserRouter. Sometimes, client might refresh the page, If it doesn't work, it is a bug.

Comment: I know it now.I have make an answer.Hope it helps you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason that you get this problem is here

```
const { languageChosen } = this.props.location.state
```

languageChose is set from this.props.location,location is set when url change to "/child/id/:id",after refreshing the page,state in Parent element change, but it won't change the location.state.And,I think you can use props in component to solve the problem.
1. set a languageChosen property in route

```
component={props => (
    <Child {...props} onChangeLanguage={this.onChangeLanguage} languageChosen={this.state.Path.state.languageChosen}/>
)}
```

2. change this in the Child component

```
const { languageChosen } = this.props.languageChosen;
```

Answer (score 1):

This code confuses me a bit but, remember when you refresh a page all the javascript gets reloaded, so you hard coded `languageChosen` to `English` in your Parent so every time you refresh the page it resets to `English`. You can either store the value in localStorage and check for its existence on refresh, or add it to your route path `child/id/:id/:language`

Then if you are using React Router v4, in your child component use `this.props.match.params.language` and it will render the given language.